# How can I execute an 'if' statement only once per iteration in a for loop?

Tags: c, string, loops

Assuming there are no duplicate words in either list, I would like to compare the words of listA with the words in listB.
If there is a match, I want to print the word that matches and compare the next 'n' words in listB to see if there is a match.
Likewise, if there is no match, (i.e once I reach the last word in listA), I want to print the word that could not be found and compare the next 'n' words in listB to see if there is a match.

I am stuck on how I should implement statements (if, break, continue) in my for loop so that it meets the specifications listed above.
When I run the code below, it only prints the instance in which there is a match, but it does not print anything at all if there is no match.

`alineno & blineno` refer to current line number in the arrays `aline & bline` where the words are stored

```
 // index through listA
 for(i = 0; i < alineno; i++){ 
   // index through all the words in listB
   for(j = 0; j < blineno; j++){ 
      if(strcmp(aline[i], bline[j]) == 0){
        printf("%s is in the list!", bline[j]);
      }
      continue;
      if(strcmp(aline[strlen(aline[0])-1], bline[j]) != 0){
        printf("%s is not in the list!", bline[j]);
      }
   }
 }
```

**Input:**

1. listA: Aardvark,Cat,Bear,Dog
2. listB: Cat,Badger

**Expected Output:**

> Cat is in the list!
>   Badger is not in the list!

**Actual Output:**

> Cat is in the list!

**EDIT:**

I understand that my `continue` statement is the reason why the second condition is not being checked. Removing it would print a word is / is not in the list 'j' amount of times, which is not my desired output. In other words, I would appreciate guidance on how I should implement such statements in order to meet the specifications.

Comment: Just remove the continue

Comment: The correct implementation is to use binary search on a sorted list of strings, instead of loops.

Comment: `aline[strlen(aline[0])-1]` What is this supposed to do? How is the length of the first string in the array related to the number of strings in the array?

Comment: @Gerhardh Whoops; I wanted to check the entire listA to see if there was a match, and if by the last word in listA I didn't (i.e `aline[strlen(aline[0])-1]` ), I would print that it was not in the list.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you change the loops, so you have the loop over "listB" as the outer loop, and iterate over "listA" in the inner loop.

Then you can easily set a flag in the inner loop, and `break` out of it when a match is found. In the outer loop you check this flag to decide what to print.

In *pseudo* code perhaps something like this

```
for (to_find in listB)
{
    found_flag = false;

    for (animal in listA)
    {
        if (to_find == animal)
        {
            found_flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found_flag)
        printf("Animal found");
    else
        printf("Animal not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `continue` is always executed; you will never reach your second `if`.

Answer (score -1):

First, use `goto`, like this:

```
void something(void) {
    // index through listA
    for(int i = 0; i < alineno; i++){ 
        // index through all the words in listB
        for(int j = 0; j < blineno; j++){ 
            if(strcmp(aline[i], bline[j]) == 0){
                printf("%s is in the list!", bline[j]);
                goto doneAnimal;
            }
        }
        printf("%s is not in the list!", bline[i]);
doneAnimal: ;
    }
}
```

Second; to avoid the risk of "goto is bad" nonsense (see Historical Note below), make the code harder to read by splitting it into 2 different functions, so that you can convert the `goto` into a `return`, like this:

```
void something(void) {
    // index through listA
    for(int i = 0; i < alineno; i++){ 
        doAnimal(i, blineno);
    }
}


void doAnimal(int i, int blineno) {
    for(int j = 0; j < blineno; j++){ 
        if(strcmp(aline[i], bline[j]) == 0){
            printf("%s is in the list!", bline[j]);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("%s is not in the list!", bline[i]);
}
```

**Historical Note**

Once upon a time higher level languages (like assembly language) did not have structured programming features (`do`, `while`, `break`, `continue`, `switch`, ...). Instead programmers would write code using `goto`, like (e.g.) "`if(x < MAX) goto loopStart;` instead of a "`} while(x < MAX);`.

To encourage the adoption of structured programming features, in 1968 Edsger W. Dijkstra wrote a letter to the editor of ACM entitled "go to statement considered harmful". This letter had the desired effect - structured programming features (`do`, `while`, `break`, `continue`, `switch`, ...) were adopted in all major languages.

However; it also had one unintended side-effect - the letter was a little too effective; and ignorant people (that failed to read the letter or understand its context) started becoming zealots, making their code worse (for cases where the new structured language features aren't enough) to avoid goto without understanding why, and encouraging other people to make their code worse without understanding why.

Examples of this include complicating code by introducing extra variables purely for the sake of avoiding a simpler `goto`, and/or complicating code to introduce extra branches purely for the sake of avoiding a simpler `goto`.

Later (in conversations with Donald E. Knuth); Dijkstra himself said "*Please don't fall into the trap of believing that I am terribly dogmatical about [the go to statement]. **I have the uncomfortable feeling that others are making a religion out of it**, as if the conceptual problems of programming could be solved by a single trick, by a simple form of coding discipline!*"

Sadly; once ignorance begins to spread common sense is fighting a losing battle.

Comment: Your versions aren't equivalent, the return statement here is similar to a `break` rather than the `goto` from the first snippet. Replace `goto` with `return ;` then otherwise keep the code as-is, but add an outer wrapper function.

Comment: @Lundin: Looks the same to me - in both cases (`goto` and `return`) execution goes back to the same place at end of the outer `for(int i = 0; i < alineno; i++)` loop. If the `return` was similar to a `break` it would be broken (it'd print "found" then print "not found", then return).

Comment: Ah nevermind, I misread the code, thought you broke both loops. But that means there's absolutely no reason to use goto here, it's just obfuscation. The inner loop should be written as `int j;
for(j = 0; j < blineno; j++) 
  if(strcmp(aline[i], bline[j]) == 0)
    break;` and then immediately after it there should be `if(j == blineno)
  printf("%s is not in the list!", bline[i]);
else
  printf("%s is in the list!", bline[j]);`.

Comment: @Lundin: If you like worse performance (extra conditional branches), and more unnecessary code (making it harder to read and more error prone); then sure, you could do it wrong like that.

Comment: On the topic of pre-mature optimization, your version is already the one with all the performance issues to begin with. As mentioned, the correct solution here is to use binary search or hash tables etc. Using the wrong method to begin with and then moaning about an additional branch doesn't seem like the correct approach to properly optimizing this code.

Comment: @Lundin: Separate issues (best way to implement the requested algorithm vs. best algorithm).

Comment: There exists no best way to write intrinsically inefficient code.

Comment: @Lundin: Wrong. The best way to implement a "potentially less good" (but potentially better, e.g. when simplicity is far more important than performance) algorithm is the implementation that gives the best compromise between readability and performance.

Comment: Yep and that's what I did. If performance doesn't matter anyway - because `strcmp` contains countless branches and you have a big f-in `printf` right there in the loop - then go with the most readable version.

Comment: @Lundin: Added a "Historical Note" to help you understand.

Comment: I know all about "beating the dead horse since 1968 considered harmful", thank you very much. This isn't what this is about.

Comment: It isn't obvious that either version is more effective, though it is very obvious what makes up the bottlenecks. And the question was never about how how to manually and pre-maturely optimize the code. The fear of goto is in your head, my argument was always about readability and never about performance. Obviously we can instead write it all in inline assembler with non-conditional jumps both up and down.

Comment: @Lundin: I'd optimistically hope that (assuming a modern optimizing compiler) the compiler is able to generate the same end result for all versions of the code. The issue is code readability (e.g. how many nanoseconds it takes a human to correctly understand the control flow of the original source at first sight); where `break;` then `if`/`else` is obviously more convoluted than `goto` (given that `break;` is essentially just "goto in disguise" and that adding more to "either goto or goto in disguise" is adding more).

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is probably binary search or a hash table, depending on the amount of data. That being said, the code could be improved in the following way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < alineno; i++)
{ 
  int j;
  for(j = 0; j < blineno; j++)
  {
    if(strcmp(aline[i], bline[j]) == 0)
      break;
  }

  if(j == blineno)
    printf("%s is not in the list!", aline[i]); 
  else
    printf("%s is in the list!", bline[j]);
}
```

Note: `aline[i]` not `bline[i]` in the printf. `bline[i]` would be a potential array out of bounds bug, if `alineno` and `blineno` are allowed to have different lengths.